# How to make communicate between nginx and php container

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, webserver, docker

I have `PHP web application` and i want to convert it into `docker`.

I have these containers

```
mysql
php
nginx
```

I have source code in my host folder as `/var/www/site1`

Now when i launch nginx , then i can mount `site1` to nginx as `/usr/nginx/share/html`

But i am not sure how does i link with PHP conainer. Can't i have stand alone PHP container with only PHP installed or I need to have some webserver along with PHP

Comment: What's in the PHP container? PHP-files or some actual installation?

Comment: @wassgren php conatiner has just php installed with all libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My view on docker containers is that each container typically represents *one process*. E.g. *mysql* or *nginx* as in your example. Containers typically communicates with each other [using networking](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/) or via [shared files in volumes](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/).

Each container runs its own operating system (typically specified in the `FROM`-section in your `Dockerfile`. In your case, you are suggesting that the *nginx*-container runs in one process with one operating system and that the *php-libraries* run in a different process (in a different os). I'm not sure if this is doable but it seems as if it is a strange way of doing things.

My suggestion is that you create two containers:

- `nginx+php` - this container holds the PHP installation as well as the Nginx-stuff
- `mysql` - this container contains the database

The container can communicate via classic networking or as [linked containers](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/).

However, the PHP-files that you wish to execute (i.e. your website) should be dynamically mounted as a [data volume](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#data-volumes) on the `nginx+php` container or as [data volume container](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/).